# Using Pandas with imported excel file from Django and creating output file for user to download.

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am interested in creating an app through Django to do the following workflow. Would be interested to know if there are any packages/framework that makes this whole process less complicated.

1.) Allow user to upload an excel file.

2.) Reads the file and stores it into a pandas dataframe.

3.) Connect to an existing database (I use mssql 2016) and store certain data into Pandas dataframes.

4.) Manipulate stored dataframes to create a final dataframe.

5.) Create an excel file using the final dataframe for user to download

I am mainly interested in frameworks that makes step 2,3,5 easier.

Thanks

Comment: 2.) https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html  and 5.) https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question seems quite broad, and might be closed for that reason. Can you be any more specific? Are there any particular elements you're having issues with?